# How to build a customized ext3 filesystem

Tags: linux, compilation, virtual-machine, ext3

I want to do some experiments in ext3's source code. Any pointer on how to compile it and make it usable?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, rebuilding the kernel is how it is done.  That creates a certain amount of work to build and start, but it may be less effort than other approaches, especially if your modifications are not extensive, so would not need a great deal of debugging.

Another approach would be to build ext3fs as a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) module.  That should make debugging easier, but it might be more work to get extfs to build that way.  I have never attempted it.